# Do you "debate about whether" or "debate whether"?

Tags: sentence-construction

A little under a million years ago, the briny waters of the Baltic Sea began flooding into the cold North Atlantic: geologists are still debating ***_*__*_***

(a) **about** whether the flood was gradual or cataclysmic.

(b)           whether the flood was gradual or cataclysmic.

Which option is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

This question has in fact [been asked on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/81552/2637). It didn't generate a lot of interest, but as my answer there shows, *debate* isn't usually followed by  *about* in such constructions (I personally don't like the usage).

The relevant usage figures from Google Books are *they debated whether [to do something]*: 11,700 hits, but *"they debated **about** whether"* gets only 87. So go with the vast majority - don't include "about".

As to the *reason*, I think it really comes down to established idiomatic preference. Possibly influenced by the fact that *discuss* is syntactically very close to *debate* (in which context it's worth noting that [they discussed **about** whether](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20discussed%20whether%22&oq=%22they%20discussed%20whether%22&gs_l=serp.3...2568192.2568192.1.2568793.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.E5nz4malItQ&pbx=1&biw=1296&bih=930&cad=cbv&sei=nGC3Ua_-EtDY0QX5oICoCQ#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20discussed%20about%20whether%22&oq=%22they%20discussed%20about%20whether%22&gs_l=serp.3...3540.5143.0.5487.6.6.0.0.0.0.68.344.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.8bkDawdOG2k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=575db4e7c24bc40c&biw=1296&bih=930) gets only 2 hits, compared to 35,900 for [they discussed whether](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20discussed%20whether%22&oq=%22they%20discussed%20whether%22&gs_l=serp.3...2568192.2568192.1.2568793.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.E5nz4malItQ&pbx=1&biw=1296&bih=930&cad=cbv&sei=nGC3Ua_-EtDY0QX5oICoCQ)).

To my mind, *debate* and *discuss* both equate to *talk **about***, so the word *about* is already implied anyway.

Comment: +1 especially for the last sentence. I think that's exactly the reason; the additional *about* is redundant, and so sounds wrong.

Comment: @WendiKidd: I'm not sure you can really say the last sentence "explains" our idiomatic preference. After all, just the word *talk* can imply *about* in certain usages (*"Let's not talk politics"*, for example). And I doubt many people care one way or the other about whether ["And did you relate to the President that Ms. Lewinsky asked about whether he was going to leave the First Lady at the end of the term?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22asked+about+whether+he+was+going+to+leave%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) validly includes the word "about".

Comment: Fumble, how sounds to your British ears "debate *as to* whether"?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I don't think so. Bear in mind what you *debate* is normally "a topic/issue", which you'd ordinarily expect to be a ***noun***. I think it's already stretching things to call *"whether [something is true]"* a "noun phrase", and it would be even harder to apply that classification to *"as to whether [something is true]"*. Also, no-one ever says they'll *debate **if** something is true*. You're only allowed to use *whether* at all because it's an established idiom, I think.